# How to position text left, center, and right with a line in the middle?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create the following:

```
Left Text - - - - - - Center Text - - - - - - Right Text
```

Where - - - - - is a 1px dashed line and is in the middle of the text height.

Comment: I believe your question was down-voted because you did not provide any code showing what you attempted. I was typing my answer while this happened. I am kinda new to contributing here so not sure if I did anything wrong by giving you the complete answer here.

Comment: @Simran you didn't do something *wrong* but you may encourage people to ask such question again which is not what we want here as it's a place for high Q&A and not *I don't know how to do, do it for me*. So better avoid answering as you may also waste your time if the question is closed/deleted later.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Makes perfect sense. I had just finished posting the solution when I noticed the down-votes. This is only the third day I have been contributing, still getting my bearings.

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox container with `space-between`. The dashed lines are a border on 1px height spans. Make sure the text spans do not grow with `flex: 0 0 auto;`

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.container .text {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.container .dashed {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  border-top: 1px dashed #000;
  margin: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="text">Left Text</span>
    <span class="dashed"></span>
    <span class="text">Center Text</span>
    <span class="dashed"></span>
    <span class="text">Right Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/s59rzh4b/

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="center">
    <span class="middle">More text</span>
  </div>
  <span class="left">Some text</span>
  <span class="right">Even more...</span>
</div>
```

```
.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.outer > * {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 5px;
  top: 0;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
}

.middle {
  background: white;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
html, body, .grid-container { height: 100%; margin: 0; }

.grid-container *:after { 
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "t1 t2 t3" ". . ." ". . .";
 txt-align: center;
  
}

.t1 { grid-area: t1; }

.t2 { grid-area: t2; }

.t3 { grid-area: t3; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="t1">sfsfds -----------------------</div>
  <div class="t2">dsfsdf -------------------</div>
  <div class="t3">dsfdsf -----------------------</div>
</div>
```

this??